# Mockito verify returns error "Invalid use of argument matchers! 1 matchers expected, 3 recorded"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

The Class structure is as follows:

```
Class A{
    private B b;

    public void methodA(int x, String y, String z){
        if methodB(int x, String y, methodC(String z)){
            // do stuff
        } else {
            //do stuff
        }
    }

    public boolean methodB(int p, String q, int r){
        //do stuff
        return c; //boolean
    }

    public Integer methodC(String x){
        // do stuff
        return y; //Integer
    }
}
```

I’m writing a unit test for methodA, and I wish to make sure methodB is called only once.

I tried using Mockito for this.

```
public class TestModule{
    @Mock
    B b;

    @InjectMocks
    A a;

    @Before
    Public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    // other tests

    @Test
    public void testMethodA(){
        Mockito.when(a.methodB(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(Mockito.anyBoolean());
        verify(a, times(1)).methodB(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt());
    } 
}
```

I'm getting an error: 
Invalid use of argument matchers! 
1 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
    pointing to the line of code "Mockito.when ..." three times.

I'm not very sure what's going wrong. Please help me figure it out. Also is there a better or easier way to do this, that I'm missing?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are not supposed to use an `ArgumentMatcher` like `anyBoolean()` inside the `thenReturn` function. Those are for matching arguments only. Return a real value instead.

Comment: Also you can not use `Mockito.when` on a non-mock object (`a`). You want to define behaviour on your mock `b` instead. However your code example does not show what `b` is used for. `a` is your class under test and should not be mocked.

Comment: Thank you @second. I mocked b cause I had other methods to test, which are working perfectly fine. Thank you for the clarification on ArgumentMatcher and Mockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you misunderstood the use of mockito in general.

- I assume that you want to test the real A class (in particular the behaviour of methodA), but...

  you never call  (*exercise* in testing terms) it.
  instead you wrongly used `Mockito.when` method that is used for *stubbing* methods.
- I don't understand the meaning of `b` attribute. You injected a mocked version of it inside A, but... you never used it.
- Let me stress that the calls to internals method should be not tested in general (verify just calls to externals ones).
- usually you check (`Mockito.verify()`) behaviours of mocked objects
- if you want to check real object you have to **spy** them.

  So a possible solution of the (not very interesting) problem to check internal call of the real SUT object is:

  ```
  public class TestModule{

    A a;

    @Test
    public void testMethodAcallsInternalMethodB(){
      //SETUP
      a = Mockito.spy(new A()); // to be able to verify behaviour of the SUT

      //EXERCISE
      a.methodA(5, "foo", "baa");

      //VERIFY
      Mockito.verify(a, times(1))
        .methodB(
          Mockito.eq(5),
          Mockito.eq("foo"),
          Mockito.anyInt()
        );
    } 
  }
  ```